# Ionic Framework: Not loading google maps library on device

Tags: android, cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework

I am trying to implement Google maps in ionic app. The map library is loading on web browser but throwing 404 on device.

To implement maps I have installed "whitelist" and "geolocation" plugins as below:

ionic plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git

ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation

Also, added access origin="*" to config.xml. 
Please, help me in this regard.

Thank you.

Comment: Follow this tutorial [link](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/10/implement-google-maps-using-ionicframework/)

Answer (score 3):

Whitelist plugin alone is not enough. You will also need to use an appropriate security meta tag, mentioned in the official whitelist plugin documentation.

But there's one thing missing from that documentation. This meta tag must be adjusted to specific needs, in this case for Google Maps V3 API.

This is a required meta tag I can confirm works with Google Maps:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
```

If you need more references you can find them in my blog article on this topic:

http://www.gajotres.net/using-cordova-geoloacation-api-with-google-maps-in-ionic-framework/

I can even send you a working example.

Comment: Thank you very much for quick reply. I tried with the above meta tag you have given then also it is throwing below error: 

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status  404 https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKeyhere&sensor=true

Comment: Is your device connected to internet?

Comment: I have the exact same problem, the CSP is correct, and the page still responds a 404...

Comment: try removing the sensor part from the url